# How to get todays day in dd format in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

How do I keep the format of the day and month as always having dd/mm?

Currently if it is under 10 it will print a single number like 5 rather than 05 or 08.

```
today = date.today()

print(today)
print(today.day)
print(today.month)
```

Output:

```
2015-08-05
5
8
```

What I want:

```
05
08
```

Comment: this should help:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: You're just getting a number, you can format it however you want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
print(today.strftime("%d"))
print(today.strftime("%m"))
05
08
```

A leading `0` means octal using python2 and is invalid syntax in python3 so you need to use a string if you want to have a leading 0. You could use `str.format` and pad but not much point when you can do it all with you date object.